# Has anyone worked with silverlight streaming sdk?

Tags: silverlight, audio, streaming

I am developing a web app using silverlight. I read that Microsoft offers 10 gigabytes of free hosting for streaming video \ audio files. My question is as following: Have any of you worked with the SDK supporting this? Is it possible to upload a video \ audio file to the server from one silverlight client and stream it to other silverlight clients?

Comment: I believe it is more of an HTTP hosting solution, where your "streaming" video is really just served over HTTP. I've honestly been using Amazon S3 and CloudFront instead - not free, but much more widely used imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked with the Silverlight Streaming API quite a bit for the [Video.Show](http://videoshow.codeplex.com/) reference application, in Silverlight 1.0. We did the upload to Silverlight Streaming from our webserver, but with Silverlight 3's support for PUT operations and improvements to the Silverlight Streaming API to support single file uploads, it looks like you'd be able to upload single videos directly from your Silverlight application.

[Silverlight Streaming API info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304456.aspx)

Note - the most difficult part will be the network calls from your Silverlight upload application to the Silverlight Streaming SDK, so I'd definitely prototype that first.

As for the media playback, that works just fine - SLS gives you a URL to your media, and you plug it into a MediaControl as you would any other media.